# Getting display text as ###### for some of the cell in excel after writing from Vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I am writting to an excel file from my vb code. The code goes as below

```
xlsheet3 = xlBook.Sheets.Add(After:=xlSheet)

With xlsheet3

.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "@"

.Cells(j + 1, 5) = someStringValue 'Here "j" is a row counter and this line is in a "for loop"  

end with
```

After writing to excel, most of the cells in excel are correct. But some of the cell's text comes as ####### however if I click on the cell, formula bar shows the correct result. I have tried giving single code before adding the text still that did not help.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is not any issue with your code. You need to increase the width of the column or have to use word wrap. In excel if your value is not fully visible it shows it is "######".

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is, how other cells in the same column having charecters more than these are coming correctly whereas these few cells are displaying a long line of #### ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If widening and wrapping text doesn't work and the format is set to text which allows display of only 255 characters, try changing the format to general.

Answer (score 0):

This just indicates that the cell is too small for showing the result: make it wider.

Answer (score 0):

See https://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong for some common reasons why Excel displays "######" in cells.

Either the cell is too narrow to display the contents or the contents are over 256 characters.

Check what you're writing to the cell. If it's not too long then all you need to do is resize the column to fit the new contents.

Comment: I have text more than 10,000 charecters, but they are comming properly on the same column but in different rows.

Comment: Hello, finally I am able to resolve it with the below code. If .Cells(j + 1, 5).text.ToString.StartsWith("##") Then .Cells(j + 1, 5).NumberFormat = "General" End If                         Excel displays ### when the cell content contains just text and it exceeds 256 characters and the cell format is set to "Text". Usually, setting the cell format to "General" fixes this problem as mentioned in the link http://superuser.com/questions/65556/excel-displays-for-long-text-whats-wrong. But still not sure how other cell values bigger than this are coming properly with NumberFormat as "Text". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is simply what Excel does when the data in a column is too wide to be displayed in the current column width. Make the column slightly wider and you will see all your data.

To autosize the column so it is wide enough to display all its data, double click the column divider at the right edge of the column, in the header bar.

Comment: I have tried widening the column and even double clicked on the edge. That is not helping. added the code .Cells(j + 1, 5).wraptext = True. still not working. The most piculiar thing is other rows on the same column which are having more charecters than some of these rows are comming correctly.